# Disable logging messages from junit test

Tags: logging, junit

I have created a sample class called ToTest and wrote a junit test for the class ToTest. When I run the Junit test, I see lot of log messages printed on eclipse console. How can I disable logging from third party classes and print logs only from my class.
I'm not using any log4j.xml or properties file, but I still wonder how it gets printed.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Logging to the console is the default for many frameworks. So, what I suggest is the following:

First - optionally - clean up your logging. Determine which logging frameworks are used and decide on one, routing the others to that one, which can be a pain in the ... behind, but can often be done. Having multiple logging frameworks doing the actual logging is not helpful.

Second, assuming you are using maven, you can simply put logging configuration files into the main/test/resources folder, where they'll only be visible when testing but not during runtime. Another possibility would be to add a static initializer to a class in main/test/src, which then does the disabling of your loggers via java code, which is sometimes possible.

The details are mostly depending on which logging frameworks you are actually using. If you are using maven, the dependency hierarchy can show you that quite easily.

Comment: Just to supplement this answer:

If you are using specs2 and Logback then

* In your `test` source dir, create `resources` dir
* Put your `logback-test.xml` file in there